# Уменьшение времени сохранения сессии nodejs

Tags: node.js

Использую nodejs как локальный сервер для тестирования своего проекта.
самый обычный `server.js`с подключённным `node-static`

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Проблема в том, что состояние где-то сохраняется, скорее всего в настройках `nodejs`, потому что простая перезагрузка страницы через `Ctrl` + `F5`не обновляет изменённые файлы проекта, но потом минут через 15 страницы обновляются. Проблема начала появляться после того как начал использовать $.ajax в Jquery, конечно. Я не претендую на прямое указание где и какой изменить параметр (хотя очень хочется), возможно другие пути решения, без фундаментальных перестроек типа использования другого локального сервера, настройки виртуальной среды  т.д.

Comment: `new static.Server('.', { cache: -1 });`

Comment: `static -H '{"Cache-Control": "no-cache, must-revalidate"}'`

Comment: @nörbörnën благодарю. Я сначала увидел Ваш комментарий, потом немного порыл, залез в сам `node-static.js` и нашел там строку `this.cache = 3600`; Я не углублялся в `nodejs` и меня смутила цифра **3600**, я подумал всего 4 секунды, значит не то, а это, видимо, время в секундах. Я поменял вручную в самом файле, перезапустил сервер, вроде стали обновляться страницы. Будьте добры поставить свой комментарий ответом, я отмечу звёздочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static) к node-static описан параметр позволяющий отключить отсылку заголовка `Cache-Control` посылаемого при отдаче файла:

> **Options when creating an instance of Server**
>
> *cache*
>
> Sets the `Cache-Control` header.
>
> `example: { cache: 7200 }`
>
> Passing a number will set the cache duration to that number of
>   seconds. Passing false will disable the Cache-Control header.
>
> **Defaults to 3600**

Вот как это применяется на практике:

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('../', {cache: false});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

А если становиться совсем злым буратино то можно написать и вот так:

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('../', {cache: false, headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0'}});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Исчерпывающе! Остаётся желать найти время тоже разобраться в документации.